# How can I use the [color] directive in a text element like span?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to use the `[color]` directive which is used in Angular Material buttons to determine to colors.

```
<button mat-button color="primary">Primary</button>
<button mat-button color="accent">Accent</button>
<button mat-button color="warn">Warn</button>
```

**Question:** How can I set these `[color]` directives to use it with `<span>` or other text elements (h1, h2, ...)?

I expect to use it like:

```
<span color="primary">This text has my primary theme color</span>
```

**I don't want to:**

- set classes to the span
- use `!important`
- use `ngClass`

Comment: do what the material team did, create a [directive](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives).

Comment: This would be too easy :). If there is a way to make an abstraction out of it. Why not? Colors are defined, don't need an additional wrapper.

Comment: Well if there is no other way then I'll take the most obvious one.

Comment: angular material components take color as `input` an apply appropriate classes to their inner elements. it is not a directive

Comment: @Andrei that is correct - my bad. The material team actually uses [inputs](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/555037a8e8de81d1cafbe31100c72b3a085dfe5b/src/material/form-field/form-field.ts#L147) the suggestion remains however, stick to directives.

Answer (score -1):

Just wrap it in a button ?

```
<button mat-icon-button color="primary"><span >This text has my primary theme color</span></button>
```

https://stackblitz.com/angular/aprongvrgkr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbutton-overview-example.html